# JQuery detecting click interactions on nested elements causing huge loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging

Attempting to add a click event to a button that is nested between multiple elements (ul, div.col, li, div.panel, div.panel-body). I am able to access it with the below code, however as if I click on the page more than a few times the console.logs begin to loop and **execute thousands of times**.

I am nearly positive it is the nesting of the functions causing this. But I do not have a thorough enough background in JQuery to be able to tell exactly what the browser is doing.

Here is my JQuery code:

```
        $('#displayList #col1').click(function(){
        console.log('clicked col');
        $('li').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(id);
            $('div.panel').click(function(){
                console.log('clicked panel');
                $('div.panel-body').click(function(){
                    console.log('clicked panel body');
                    $('button').click(function(){
                        console.log('clicked button');
                        return;
                    });
                    return;
                });
                return;
            });
            return;
        });
        return;
    });
```

Could one of you wonderful JQuery gurus explain what is causing this bug and point me in a better path for checking if the button has been clicked or if it hasnt(just the panel was clicked).

Also, does anyone know a good and preferably free debugging program that I can use to step through JQuery code execution by execution?

Thank you so much for your knowledge

Comment: What's your goal? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Registering click handlers within click handlers means new click handlers will be created every time something is clicked and thats why things eventually get executed thousands of times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are binding an event handler inside another event handler. So whenever the later event occurs, new handlers are added, Eventually causing multiple handlers for same event on same element.

Your code should look something like

```
$('#displayList #col1').click(function(){
    console.log('clicked col');
});
 $('li').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
     console.log(id);
});
$('div.panel').click(function(){
     console.log('clicked panel');
});
$('div.panel-body').click(function(){
      console.log('clicked panel body');
});
$('button').click(function(){
      // The following will be executed when the button is clicked 
      console.log('clicked button');
});
```

Assume you have the following markup:

```
<div id="container>
  <div id="parent">
    <button>Click Me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the event handlers:

```
$("#container").click(function(){
  console.log("container got a click!");
});
$("#parent").click(function(){
  console.log("parent got a click!");
});
$("#parent button").click(function(){
  console.log("button got a click!");
});
```

Now if you click the button output will be

```
//button got a click!
//parent got a click!
//container got a click!
```

When you click an element, all of it's ancestors will also receive a click event by default, and the corresponding event handler will be called, if any - This is called event bubbling.
If you don't need any specific functionality then you don't need a handler so bubling won't hurt.

However, You can prevent this behaviour by calling the [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) method of event object inside the event handler:

```
$("#parent button").click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log("button got a click!");
});
```

output will be

```
//button got a click!
```

There is one more event propagation method in some browsers (*Only event bubbling model is supported by all the major browsers*), you can read about it in detail @[quirksmore: Event order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

As [DFTR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881421/dftr) mentioned in comments,

> Visual studio allows break points in javascript code, when launching an application within internet explorer. Another debugging tool is firebug, which is a pretty neat firefox extension

Comment: This is the correct answer. You shouldn't nest click events. T J left out one part though. For example, Visual studio, when launching an application within internet explorer, allows break points in javascript code. Another debugging tool is firebug, which is a pretty neat firefox extension.

Comment: TJ, thank you for your quick response. But this solution does not work. Would the button being inside of a list item be the reason?

Comment: @BillHeadrick That won't be an issue, `$('button')` will target all the buttons (*`<button>` elements*) that are present in the document  at the time the code runs. Is your code inside `$(document).ready()`?, are you adding the button dynamically afterwards?

Comment: Thank you so much TJ. I ran this on a localhost test page and it worked as expected so the bug must be somewhere else in my code. I will track it down, but thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: I am adding the button dynamically afterwards, does this make a difference?

Comment: Yes..! In that case we'll make use of this event bubbling: We'll add the event handler for a parent element which is static. When this elements gets a click, we'll check whether the `target` was a button or not, if so we'll execute our logic. This is called [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). jQuery provides an easy method [on()](http://api.jquery.com) for delegating events from v1.71

Comment: Wow. I was looking in the completely wrong area. I need to use .on(). You are so right.

Answer (score 2):

Might help you.

if you need to bind event to button, you should use [**descendant selector**](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$('#displayList #col1 li div.panel div.panel-body button').click(function() {
    console.log('clicked button');
});
```